# Docker - I'm attempting to run the hello-world example from the Docker site, but localhost:4000 renders nothing

Tags: docker

I'm referring to the example located here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app

My attempt to run the app works as expected:

`docker_test docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

But, when I navigate to localhost:4000, the page doesn't load. Instead, I see a message in Chrome that reads "This site cannot be reached."

Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use docker toolbox? If so, localhost won't work as docker runs in a VM

Comment: I'm not sure. I have something named Kitematic installed, though. I'm on a Mac, if it matters.

Comment: @TarunLalwani, you are correct.